# how to get rid of /index at end

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-restserver

I am using PHP codeigniter and chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver.

In log file I am seeing 404. because some how **/index** is getting append at end.
correct url is **api/CurrentYear**

```
DEBUG - 2016-02-02 02:14:48 --> UTF-8 Support Enabled
DEBUG - 2016-02-02 02:14:48 --> Global POST, GET and COOKIE data sanitized
ERROR - 2016-02-02 02:14:48 --> 404 Page Not Found: api/CurrentYear/index
```

Can anyone give me clue why /index is getting append at end or any solution.

my .htaccess look like this.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(favicon\.ico|apple-touch-icon.*\.png)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule (.+) index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: are you remove index.php in config file ?

Comment: yes it like $config['index_page'] = '';

Comment: share you host url ?

Comment: its like http://example.com/api/currentYear

Comment: When one omits the function name after the controller, Codeiginiter goes for the default one, which is the `index` function. That is why it is added to you url. Thus accessing the controller `CurrentYear` without specifying a function will make CodeIgniter look for its `index` function. In this case, as you extended REST_Controller, the function must be called `index_<HTTP-METHOD>()`. If you do not have the function, 404 error will be returned. (Assuming that `api` is a folder and `CurrentYear` is a controller).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to remove `index.php` from URL then follow code will surely works for you.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
```

Comment: can we remove "index" from end?

Answer (score 0):

Please remove the index.php in codeIgniter Framework config file

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

And apply below htaccess coding

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|css|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me

```
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpg|shtml|ico|swf|wav|mp3|less|cur)
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule (.*) index.php?p=$1 [QSA]
```